# Can you use a MagJack for isolation of RS422 for something like UART?

Tags: pcb-design, isolation, signal-integrity

Say, I dont want to use optocouplers they either too slow or take up too much same on the board. And digital isolators are too costly or out of stock because of semiconductor shortage.

Consider this setup:
SENDER: Microcontroller-UART(TM4C123) connected to RS422-transreciver(SN75176) connected to a MagJack(HR911130A).
RECIVER: RS422-transreciver(SN75176)

Not that there is not a magjack at reciver end, since this a off the shelf device which uses UART over RS422 (basically Modbus device but that is not important) that I need to communicate to.

I assume it should work since a RX/TX UART has no DC signal just pulses and theortically small width pulses should pass just fine over the magjack provided I don't drop the baudrate too low. For example lets consider 57600 baudrate.

Would this setup work?

And If it can, can I extend it to control some motor drives with pulse direction interface, except that it ain't pulse direction, I will use Clockwise, CouterClowkwise mode to avoid any signals not a pulse.

Thanks

Comment: "RX/TX UART has no DC signal just pulses"  "=false", however your stepper control line may be "true" for the Step CW,CCW signal.  There must be some logic to convert in between.  Otherwise OK.  Show overall specs and why you chose that converter.

Comment: I did some brushup of how UART works, apparently I had forgotten UART has a idle state of 0V, BUT its not, it is logic high. If UART had 0V as steady would it have worked then? I can see logic high steady state as the only DC component, everything else seems it could pass thru the transformers.

Comment: How did you intend to encode step pulses in a byte?

Comment: I dont understand, why do you mean by encode step pulse in a byte? Do you mean to ask how to capture step pulse encoding at the recivers end?

Comment: then how will you define ' Clockwise, CouterClowkwise"

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Ohh that is actually pretty simple, the microcontroller will be genertaing Clockwise, Counterclockwise signals. And the microcontroller firware is written by me. So I have full control on the logic of step pulses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would this setup work?

Almost certainly not.  All Ethernet data bitstreams are encoded to give them an average value of 0 V.  IOW, the line signal has no DC component.  The bitstreams in and out of a standard UART are not so encoded, and can have a significant DC component.  In RS-422, RS-485, and RS-232 signalling, they can sit at whatever voltage represents a "0" state indefinitely.  This will not go through the transformers in the jack.

Here is an example of this type of line coding:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_code

Comment: But if you put your signal through an appropriate modem ....

Comment: Just for reference, RS-232/422/485 does not mean UART or any specific bitstream. For example AES3 audio is sent over RS-422 and transformer isolation is even preferred.

Comment: Note that you may still be able to construct such signals, if your MCU has advanced features like configurable logic. ASK and FSK are also possibilities, mixing with, or modifying, a timer signal (Manchester being a special case of FSK).  Afraid I'm not familiar with TM4C123 to be more specific.

Comment: Justme - That's because AES3 uses a variation of Manchester code, which again has no DC component.

Comment: @AnalogKid I did some brushup of how UART works, apparently I had forgotten UART has a idle state of 0V, BUT its not, it is logic high. If UART had 0V as steady would it have worked then? I can see logic high steady state as the only DC component, everything else seems it could pass thru the transformers.

Comment: @AnalogKid I know (it reads in my answer). I meant the wording in your answer, where you talk about bitstreams in RS-232/422/485 but you clearly mean UART bitstream instead, as RS-xxx PHYs can be used to send any bitstream.

Comment: You are correct; I think I misread the original post.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work, as contrary to your understanding, UART does have a DC component.

Other RS-422 interfaces, which use a DC-balanced line code such as Manchester or bi-phase can use transformer isolation, e.g. AES3.